# Implementing custom OrderBy for ManyToOne relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Unfortunately, the OrderBy attribute is not supported for `ManyToOne` relations.
Is there a way to implement a custom one? Similar to the Attributes approach?

I already tried SQLFilter but as it turns out, it will not work for ORDER BY sentence.

I'm using API-platform too.

EDIT:
Implementing OrderBy on Companies.applications

```
#[ORM\OrderBy(['candidate.firstName' => 'DESC'])]
#[Groups(['opening:read'])]
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'job', targetEntity: Application::class)]
private Collection $applications;
```

Applications entity has this property

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'applications')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private ?User $candidate = null;
```

returns an error `Warning: Undefined array key \"candidate.firstName\"`
and based on this [doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/tutorials/ordered-associations.html#ordering-to-many-associations)

> The referenced field names have to exist on the targetEntity class of the #[ManyToMany] or #[OneToMany] attribute.

Comment: Explain in more detail what you are trying to do.
give some sort of example

Comment: updated my post

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your model. Are you sure there is no error ?

Comment: this was is the error message Warning: Undefined array key \"candidate.firstName\"

Answer (score 1):

The [doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/tutorials/ordered-associations.html) is quite clear, as you noted yourself, that this cannot be done. Maybe with some fancy AST Walkers, but I wouldn't recommend that.

> The DQL Snippet in OrderBy is only allowed to consist of unqualified, unquoted field names and of an optional ASC/DESC positional statement. Multiple Fields are separated by a comma (,). The referenced field names have to exist on the targetEntity class of the #[ManyToMany] or #[OneToMany] attribute.

You could denormalize your Application entity a little bit and add a `$firstName` property on that specific entity, that copies that value from the `User` entity when creating/updating the entity.

You could then rewrite your `Company` entity to:

```php
#[ORM\OrderBy(['firstName' => 'DESC'])]
#[Groups(['opening:read'])]
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'job', targetEntity: Application::class)]
private Collection $applications;
```

But having that denormalization step is really a preference and might also not be a preferable method for some.